# Series of Multiple Lengths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

The following code checks for partial matches and adds a comment for if a partial match does or does not exist (it works great!):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = {'Non-Suffix' : ['1234569', '1234554', '1234567', '1234568','Hello'], 'Suffix' : ['1234567:C', '1234568:VXCF', 'ABCDEFU', '1234569-01', '1234554-01:XC']}
x = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in x.items()})
x['"Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"?'] = x['Non-Suffix'].apply(lambda v: x['Suffix'].str.contains(v).any()).replace({True: '--'}).replace({False: 'Add to Suffix'}).replace({np.nan: '--'})
x['"Suffix" Partial Match in "Non-Suffix"?'] = x['Suffix'].str.contains('|'.join(x['Non-Suffix'])).replace({True: '--'}).replace({False: 'Remove from Suffix'}).replace({np.nan: '--'})
x
#code breaks if anything is added to 'Suffix' column
```

[image]

However, in practice, columns of the same length will not always be compared.  In fact, most of the time, columns of varying lengths will be compared.  If I add a value to the `Non-Suffix` column (`'StackOverflowIsAwesome'`), the code breaks:

```
x = {'Non-Suffix' : ['1234569', '1234554', '1234567', '1234568','Hello'], 'Suffix' : ['1234567:C', '1234568:VXCF', 'ABCDEFU', '1234569-01', '1234554-01:XC','HelloAdele']}
x = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in x.items()})
x['"Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"?'] = x['Non-Suffix'].apply(lambda v: x['Suffix'].str.contains(v).any()).replace({True: '--'}).replace({False: 'Add to Suffix'}).replace({np.nan: '--'})
x['"Suffix" Partial Match in "Non-Suffix"?'] = x['Suffix'].str.contains('|'.join(x['Non-Suffix'])).replace({True: '--'}).replace({False: 'Remove from Suffix'}).replace({np.nan: '--'})
x
#code breaks if anything is added to 'Suffix' column
```

Here is the error that confirms the differing lengths between columns:
[image]

I'd like to be able to add something (like the `'HelloAdele'` in the `Suffix` column and not have the code break.  Note: I can add values to the `Non-Suffix` column, but not the `Suffix` column.  Any tips on how to overcome this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** to ensure NaN in `Non-Suffix` column does not result in "Add to Suffix" value.

I think something like this should work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = {'Non-Suffix' : ['1234569', '1234554', '1234567', '1234568','Hello'], 'Suffix' : ['1234567:C', '1234568:VXCF', 'ABCDEFU', '1234569-01', '1234554-01:XC','HelloAdele']}
x = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in x.items()})
print()
print(x)
x['"Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"?'] = x['Non-Suffix'].apply(
    lambda v: np.nan if v is np.nan else x['Suffix'].str.contains(v).any()).replace({True: '--'}).replace({False: 'Add to Suffix'}).replace({np.nan: '--'})
x['"Suffix" Partial Match in "Non-Suffix"?'] = x['Suffix'].str.contains('|'.join(
    y for y in x['Non-Suffix'] if y is not np.nan)).replace({True: '--'}).replace({False: 'Remove from Suffix'}).replace({np.nan: '--'})
print(x)
```

We basically special-case NaN in `Non-Suffix` and set the result to np.nan (which later gets replaced by '--'), and in `Suffix` we skip NaN when building the pattern to match.

Input:

```
  Non-Suffix         Suffix
0    1234569      1234567:C
1    1234554   1234568:VXCF
2    1234567        ABCDEFU
3    1234568     1234569-01
4      Hello  1234554-01:XC
5        NaN     HelloAdele
```

Output:

```
  Non-Suffix         Suffix "Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"? "Suffix" Partial Match in "Non-Suffix"?
0    1234569      1234567:C                                      --                                      --
1    1234554   1234568:VXCF                                      --                                      --
2    1234567        ABCDEFU                                      --                      Remove from Suffix
3    1234568     1234569-01                                      --                                      --
4      Hello  1234554-01:XC                                      --                                      --
5        NaN     HelloAdele                                      --                                      --
```

Comment: How did you show the output in SO? @constantstranger

Comment: I ran this on the command line, then just copy/pasted the output of `print(x)` using triple backticks before and after.

Comment: In Jupyter Notebook or what? @constantstranger

Comment: What’s the best IDE for Python, in your opinion?

Comment: For this question, from Windows I opened `notepad` and saved the file as `test.py`, then I opened a Windows command line using `cmd` and typed `python test.py` to run the python code. After I ran it, I selected the output of the `print()` statements in the code, copied them, and pasted them into my SO answer. Regarding best IDE, I don't have a strong opinion, but Jupyter Notebook is a versatile and convenient interface that you can use in your local environment or on platforms like Google Colab, Kaggle and others, which might be helpful for you.

Comment: just noticing that the ```np.nan``` value should not have a corresponding ```Add to Suffix```.  How can I get ```np.nan```s to also show "--"? @constantstranger

I already have the code ```replace({np.nan: '--'})``` attached.

Comment: I have updated the answer to replace `False` with `np.nan` in the lambda passed to `apply()`. This then gets processed by the part of your original code that you mentioned (`replace({np.nan: '--'})`) and no longer results in an `Add to Suffix` entry.